# How to construct keyline in opencv if only the end points of the line are available?

Tags: c++, opencv, line

Opencv provides a structure called keyline, which is detected by line segment detectors. The structure has various public members such as angle, length etc.

The following class members are not clearly explained such as class_id, endPointX, endPointY, ePointInOctaveX, ePointInOctaveY, octave, startPointX, startPointY etc.

**My questions is if I have the end points of the line, can the structure members of keyline be constructed?**

```
cv::Point P1 (0,0);
cv::Point P2 (10,10);

cv::line_descriptor::KeyLine L; // How to construct L from P1 and P2?
L.octave = ??;
L.endPointX = ??;
L.endPointY = ??;
L.ePointInOctaveX = ??;
L.ePointInOctaveY = ??;
L.startPointX = ??;
L.startPointY = ??
```

Comment: Isn't that just a struct with public members?

Comment: All the public members are not documented, thus making it difficult. Editing the question to add which members are not clear.

Comment: got any API that _draws_ these things? then you can experiment. -- just declare octave to be 0 and all the other stuff to be equal. you'll know what octaves are when you've read about feature descriptors, which are commonly multi-scale.

Answer (score 2):

> My questions is if I have the end points of the line, can the structure members of keyline be constructed?

yes,you can

```cpp
cv::Point P1 (0,0);
cv::Point P2 (10,10);

cv::line_descriptor::KeyLine L;
```

In your code above,the x,y coordinates of your `P1`,`P2` correspond to the `extremes` variables in the following code, `L` corresponds to `L1` below, `octave` takes 0, and the rest of the member variables are calculated according to the following code.

```cpp
     // 测试keyLine构建
    cv::Mat testImg = cv::Mat::zeros(500, 500, CV_8UC3);
    cv::line_descriptor::KeyLine L1;

    /* fill KeyLine's fields */
    L1.startPointX = P1.x;
    L1.startPointY = P1.y;
    L1.endPointX = P2.x;
    L1.endPointY = P2.y;
    L1.octave = 0;
    L1.sPointInOctaveX = L1.startPointX;
    L1.sPointInOctaveY = L1.startPointY;
    L1.ePointInOctaveX = L1.endPointX;
    L1.ePointInOctaveY = L1.endPointY;
    L1.lineLength = (float)sqrt(pow(L1.startPointX - L1.endPointX, 2) + pow(L1.startPointY - L1.endPointY, 2));

    /* compute number of pixels covered by line */
    cv::LineIterator li(testImg, Point2f(L1.startPointX, L1.startPointY), Point2f(L1.endPointX, L1.endPointY));
    L1.numOfPixels = li.count;

    L1.angle = atan2((L1.endPointY - L1.startPointY), (L1.endPointX - L1.startPointX));
    L1.class_id = 0;
    L1.octave = 0;
    L1.size = (L1.endPointX - L1.startPointX) * (L1.endPointY - L1.startPointY);
    L1.response = L1.lineLength / max(testImg.cols, testImg.rows);
    L1.pt = Point2f((L1.endPointX + L1.startPointX) / 2, (L1.endPointY + L1.startPointY) / 2);
```

Reference [source code here](https://github.com/drozdvadym/opencv_line_descriptor/blob/9acc45a9979fc44e0e7d00e2a455a7dc536ea548/src/LSDDetector.cpp#L129).